# Can I interrogate org-export-filter info object to check if the text format is UTF-8?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

The signature of org-export-filter functions is `(data backend info)`. I want to write a function that will know if I'm exporting to ascii or latin1 or utf-8. The backend appears to be `'ascii` no matter which of the text options I'm using, so I'm wondering what is in the info data.

I'm very new to lisp of any sort so I don't even know how to think about `info` here. Is that an object, a struct, or something else? How do I dig into it?

I haven't been able to find reference documentation that describes that data structure, I'd be interested if anyone can point me to that.

Comment: The `info` parameter in export functions is a kitchen sink of a property list (see "Property lists" in the Elisp manual with `C-h i g(elisp)property lists`). That gives you the generic structure, but the keys that you can use to query the property list are partly documented [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-export-reference.html#communication), at least  the common ones. Specific export engines may define more and for those I'm afraid you'll have to read the code (`ox-ascii.el` in the Org mode tree's `lisp` subdirectory).

Comment: If you want *all* your buffers to be in UTF-8, then just set your LANG variable outside of Emacs to .e.g `en_US.utf8` or some variant thereof. That is *much* simpler than worrying about it for every different buffer.

Comment: Try customizing `org-ascii-charset` to `utf-8`.